# List Item as a page object

Tags: listview, appium, listviewitem, pageobjects

I'm working with page objects in Appium.

I've some view which contains a recyclerview with an items in it.

Each item contain several ui controls (button , image , text , etc ...

I was thinking to create a page object which represent an item in the list.

Something like that :

```
class MainView{
....
AndroidFindBy(...)
private AndroidElement list;
}


class Item{
  @AndroidFindBy(....)
  private AndroidElement button;

  @AndroidFindBy(....)
  private AndroidElement text;

  @AndroidFindBy(....)
  private AndroidElement image;

  ...
}
```

But I had a trouble to connect between the "Item" PO to the list which is in MainView.

Any ideas or what is the best practice to work in such case ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually the issue was solved with " Widget " appium's API.

https://github.com/appium/java-client/blob/master/docs/Page-objects.md#the-additional-feature